# tufte-book: captions under figure

Tags: tufte

I am using tufte-book and having troubles with the list of figures.
I am working with the following code:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,twoside,a4]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\setcaptionfont{%
  \normalfont\footnotesize
  \color{red}% <-- set color here
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\section{section 1}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{firstpicture}
\caption[title in lof]{\color{white}anything}
{\stepcounter{figure}\newline
\smallskip\noindent\small Figure \thefigure:
A nice picture}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

this will be my first picture but gives me in the list of figures

1.2 title in lof 3

which is a wrong number 1.2.

So I want to have the captions under my picture in the figure enviroment and not in the margins. Therefore I've tried to use the code above with white color for the text.

How can you set the captions in tufte-book under the figure?
(Or fix the numbering problem above?)

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following lines to the preamble of your document (between the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` lines) should reset the `figure` and `table` environments to their original (non-Tufte) styles:

```
% Reset figure and float environments to their original
% (non-Tufte) styles.
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][htbp]{%
  \@tufte@orig@float{figure}[#1]%
}{%
  \@tufte@orig@endfloat
}

\renewenvironment{table}[1][htbp]{%
  \@tufte@orig@float{table}[#1]%
}{%
  \@tufte@orig@endfloat
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks it's (almost) working. But the captions aren't centered under the figure by using \begin{figure} \centering \includegraphics{...} \caption{...} \end{figure}. How can you fix this?